# Typescript differentiate between string types

Tags: typescript

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to distinguish between two strings.

The concrete use case is this:

I am trying to typecast an API which returns different strings for the user in different places. Some interfaces return the ID (string), some return the first name, some return the active directory name, and some return the full name:

Examples:

```
// books
{
  id: "1",
  creator: "Peter Pan" // refers to the same user
}

// films
{
  id: "1",
  creator: "peterpahn" // refers to the same user
}
```

Now I would like to type the different responses so that I can distinguish between "FirstName", "IdName", "FullName" to have type safety when processing this data.

I can imagine that one solution could be to use an object with different optional parameters instead of a string, but in that case I would have to map each return value, which I wanted to avoid, because it seems to be more complex than it needs to be.

What I was hoping for would be something like this:

```
type UserId = string
type UserFirstName = string;

function showUserName(user: UserId) {
  console.log(`Name: ${user}`);
}

showUserName("Test" as UserId);
showUserName("Test" as UserFirstName); // this should throw a type error
```

Comment: See if [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) helps.

Comment: You want a `type` to differentiate between "John Doe" and "johnDoe" that works for any string? I'm not sure that is even possible. You should probably create a function that checks it during runtime. Maybe a regular expression?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking and it *might* be because there are typos.  Why would `showUserName("Test" as UserFirstName)` be an error if `UserFirstName` is the intended input type to `showUserName`?  This could be a straightforward [branded primitives](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) question, but right now I'm stumped unless you made a mistake in the question.

Comment: @jcalz you are right, it was wrong. I corrected the code.

Comment: @jcalz btw your suggestion is working for me. Thank you so much! Do you want to create a regular reply that I can accept or should I write it myself?

Comment: I can write up an answer when I get a chance (although now that we know this is a nominal typing question it might get closed as a duplicate)